# EntityFramework 6: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint Error but the parent record has been saved

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two tables in my DB, `Users` and `JobSeekerEmploymentDetails`.

```
Users
---------------------------
ID        int (Auto Generated Primary Key)
Col1      ...

JobSeekerEmploymentDetails
---------------------------
ID        int (Auto Generated Primary Key)
Col1      ...
UserId    int (Foreign Key to Users table)
```

To insert the records in the above tables, my code is as follows: (I am using `EntityFramework 6` and `AutoMapper`)

```
    public async Task<int> SaveJobSeeker(AccountInfoViewModel accountInfo, PersonalDetailViewModel personalDetail, EmploymentDetailsViewModel employmentDetails)
    {
        //create EF User object
        var user = new User {CreatedOn = DateTime.Now};

        //map data from the ViewModels into user class
        Mapper.Map(accountInfo, user);
        Mapper.Map(personalDetail, user);

        using (var db = new ITWebEntities())
        {
            //save user
            db.Users.Add(user);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            //Create new EF class object and set recently saved user Id as foreign key value
            var jobSeekerEmpDetail = new JobSeekerEmploymentDetail { UserId = user.ID };

            //Map other detail from the ViewModel object           
            Mapper.Map(employmentDetails, jobSeekerEmpDetail);

            //save emp details info
            db.JobSeekerEmploymentDetails.Add(jobSeekerEmpDetail);
            return await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

Now the `User` is saved into the DB and I can see that the value of `ID` is retrieved successfully from the saved `User` object. But the last `db.SaveChangesAsync()` statement throws the following exception.

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_EmploymentDetails_Users". The conflict occurred in database "ITWeb", table "dbo.Users", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

The constraint is set properly as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

I suppose I am doing something stupid but I am unable to figure it out. Can you help?

Comment: can you put a breakpoint to see what is user.Id on before this line is executed? var jobSeekerEmpDetail = new JobSeekerEmploymentDetail { UserId = user.ID };

Comment: Actually my last Mapping was overriding the UserId value to 0. I changed the code a little and its fine now. Thanks a lot for you comment.

Answer (score 1):

That was very simple. The line `Mapper.Map(employmentDetails, jobSeekerEmpDetail);` would actually override the `UserId` to 0 which I set correctly in previous step.  I changed it the code to set the `UserId` after the mapping has been performed and it worked.

```
public async Task<int> SaveJobSeeker(AccountInfoViewModel accountInfo, PersonalDetailViewModel personalDetail, EmploymentDetailsViewModel employmentDetails)
{
    //create EF User object
    var user = new User {CreatedOn = DateTime.Now};

    //map data from the ViewModels into user class
    Mapper.Map(accountInfo, user);
    Mapper.Map(personalDetail, user);

    using (var db = new ITWebEntities())
    {
        //save user
        db.Users.Add(user);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        //Create new EF class object and set recently saved user Id as foreign key value
        var jobSeekerEmpDetail = new JobSeekerEmploymentDetail();

        //Map other detail from the ViewModel object           
        Mapper.Map(employmentDetails, jobSeekerEmpDetail);

        jobSeekerEmpDetail.UserId = user.ID;

        //save emp details info
        db.JobSeekerEmploymentDetails.Add(jobSeekerEmpDetail);
        return await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```